# creating a session using cloudant store

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, session, cloudant

Previously i have used express session it worked well and now i have changed to cloudant sessions and when i try to run this and register / login its saying req.session is not defined which is working for normal express sessions can someone tell me what mistake i have done or how to trigger or create a session into it
This is my app.js file

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var CloudantStore = require('connect-cloudant-store')(session);
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

//connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('cloudant url');
//var db = mongoose.connection;


var Cloudant = require('cloudant');
var me = "username"; // Set this to your own account
var password = "password";

// Initialize the library with my account.
var cloudant = Cloudant({
  account: me,
  password: password
});
var db = cloudant.db.use('placements-test')

cloudant.db.list(function (err, allDbs) {
  console.log('Available Databases: %s', allDbs.join(', '))
});
var store = new CloudantStore(
  {
      url: 'url',
      databaseName: "placement-test"
    }
);
store.on('connect', function() {
  // Cloudant Session store is ready for use
  setInterval(function() { store.cleanupExpired(); }, 3600 * 1000);
});

store.on('disconnect', function() {
 // failed to connect to cloudant db - by default falls back to MemoryStore
});

store.on('error', function(err) {
 // You can log the store errors to your app log
});
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboardcat',
 store:store,
 saveUninitialized: false,
 resave: true
}));


// parse incoming requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


// serve static files from template
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/templateLogReg'));

// include routes
var routes = require('./routes/router');
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('File Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
// define as the last app.use callback
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send(err.message);
});


// listen on port 3000
app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Express app listening on port 8080');
});
```

This is my routing file

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var path = require('path');
var Cloudant = require('cloudant');
var me = "username"; // Set this to your own account
var password = "password";


var cloudant = Cloudant({
  account: me,
  password: password
});

var db = cloudant.db.use('placements-test')
// GET route for reading data
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/templateLogReg/index.html'));
});


//POST route for updating data
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // confirm that user typed same password twice
  if (req.body.password !== req.body.passwordConf) {
    var err = new Error('Passwords do not match.');
    err.status = 400;
    res.send("passwords dont match");
    return next(err);
  }

  if (req.body.email &&
    req.body.username &&
    req.body.password &&
    req.body.passwordConf) {

    var userData = {
      email: req.body.email,
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      passwordConf: req.body.passwordConf,
    }


    db.insert(userData, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('[db.insert] ', err.message);
      }
      else {
        console.log('You have created a New User');
        console.log(user);
        console.log(req.session);
        req.session.user = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/profile');
      }
    });

    /*
        User.create(userData, function (error, user) {
          if (error) {
            return next(error);
          } else {
            req.session.userId = user._id;
            return res.redirect('/profile');
          }
        });*/

  } else if (req.body.logemail && req.body.logpassword) {
    User.authenticate(req.body.logemail, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
      if (error || !user) {
        var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      } else {
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/profile');
      }
    });
  } else {
    var err = new Error('All fields required.');
    err.status = 400;
    return next(err);
  }
})

// GET route after registering
router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.session.userId)
    .exec(function (error, user) {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      } else {
        if (user === null) {
          var err = new Error('Not authorized! Go back!');
          err.status = 400;
          return res.sendFile(path.resolve('templateLogReg/index.html'));;
        } else {
          return res.sendFile(path.resolve('templateLogReg/dashboard.html'));


        }
      }
    });
});

// GET for logout logout
router.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session) {
    // delete session object
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is my old express sessions code app.js file which is working i wantsame functionality using the cloudant store hope you understood

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

//connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testForAuth');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//handle mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
  // we're connected!
});

//use sessions for tracking logins
app.use(session({
  secret: 'work hard',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));

// parse incoming requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


// serve static files from template
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/templateLogReg'));

// include routes
var routes = require('./routes/router');
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('File Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
// define as the last app.use callback
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send(err.message);
});


// listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Express app listening on port 3000');
});
```

this is router.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var path = require('path');

// GET route for reading data
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/templateLogReg/index.html'));
});


//POST route for updating data
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  // confirm that user typed same password twice
  if (req.body.password !== req.body.passwordConf) {
    var err = new Error('Passwords do not match.');
    err.status = 400;
    res.send("passwords dont match");
    return next(err);
  }

  if (req.body.email &&
    req.body.username &&
    req.body.password &&
    req.body.passwordConf) {

    var userData = {
      email: req.body.email,
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      passwordConf: req.body.passwordConf,
    }

    User.create(userData, function (error, user) {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      } else {
        console.log(req.session);
        console.log(req.session.userId);
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/profile');
      }
    });

  } else if (req.body.logemail && req.body.logpassword) {
    User.authenticate(req.body.logemail, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
      if (error || !user) {
        var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      } else {
        console.log(req.session);
        console.log(req.session.userId);
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/profile');
      }
    });
  } else {
    var err = new Error('All fields required.');
    err.status = 400;
    return next(err);
  }
})

// GET route after registering
router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.session.userId)
    .exec(function (error, user) {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      } else {
        if (user === null) {
          var err = new Error('Not authorized! Go back!');
          err.status = 400;
          return   res.sendFile( path.resolve('templateLogReg/index.html') );;
        } else {
          return     res.sendFile( path.resolve('templateLogReg/dashboard.html') );
          
          
        }
      }
    });
});

// GET for logout logout
router.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session) {
    // delete session object
    req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

please do help

Comment: Can you specify at which line of your code `req.session is not defined` error is thrown?

Comment: In the routing file 
` else {`
        console.log('You have created a New User');
        console.log(user);
        console.log(req.session); // here it is saying session is not defined
        req.session.user = user._id;  // here it is saying session is not defined
        return res.redirect('/profile');`

Comment: It is working when i tried it with mongodb and not working with cloudant store. First two code snippets are cloudant and last two are mongodb @user3405291

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when enabling the debug for connect-cloudant-store module?

```
export DEBUG=connect:cloudant-store;npm start
```

Also I would log the errors for the store:

```
store.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

One possible source for this issue could be that the session database is not created in cloudant. Enabling debuging as above should help you catch errors like that.